# Configure iPad IP address programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios4

I have a requirement where the iPad application must configure the IP address of the device to a particular IP and connect to a wireless network. I had gone through the internet but could not find any material regarding the possible solution .

I really appreciate any solution on this

Thank you

Comment: You cannot do it. The user can configure IP settings for various networks, but you cannot do it from within an app.

Comment: Device / System level things (like IP address configuration) can not be done from within a sandboxed app store app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, an iOS app doesn't have this control over the system, so this can't be done on an App Store app.